# Is it possible to get min value of integer?

Tags: javascript

In C# we have property `int.MinValue` which returns -2147483648.

Is there any way to get this value using javascript?

**EDIT**

I have found answers such as `Number.MIN_VALUE` and `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` but if you had checked that, you would have known that they don't return the value I expected.

Comment: there are times when javascript, may be talking to a C# (or Java or Scala) backend and you need to validate numbers before sent to the backend.  this is a legit question and doesn't really deserve down votes.

Answer (score 11):

Javascript does not use integers but floating point numbers. So the smallest number that can be represented is `-Number.MAX_VALUE`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE

However, such a number will not keep all digits (floating point has a limited precision).

`Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` may be what you're looking for, but it's still experimental.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_SAFE_INTEGER

Answer (score 2):

The value in C# is 2^31 * -1, so `var x = Math.pow(2,31) * -1;`

Comment: there are times when javascript, may be talking to a C# (or Java or Scala) backend and you need to validate numbers sent to the backend.  so finding the MIN_VALUE using a javascript formula such as this is a perfectly legit answer